# Closing vent hole in vinyl siding

Tags: siding, vinyl, hole-repair

Looking for any suggestions for the following situation. The house we bought had a kerosene heater in the basement and vented through the base of the house which is vinyl sided. I am removing the heater and all the piping, venting and kerosene line. This is leaving a 3 1/2" hole in the side of the house where the vent piping went through. I looked at possibly using a dryer vent to close up the hole, but they look to be a standard 4" size. I am finding many suggestions on how to patch vinyl siding, but not any that address closing up a hole. I have looked at some vinyl vents, but they are not the correct size. Any ideas, suggestions or feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have spare siding? What color is it? How is "patching" siding different from "closing up a hole"? A photo would be great.

Comment: Yep, usually if you want a hole in the siding gone, you replace that piece of siding. Otherwise grab a 4" hole saw and put in a dyer vent, or get one of those vinyl siding bits intended to mount an outside wall light on and cut a hole to fit that over the hole you have.

Comment: I was getting hung up on the fact that there was a hole all the way through the house to the cellar. But replacing the siding is a great idea. Owner did not leave any scrap pieces and siding is probably almost 30 years old. However, I have a guy coming next week to replace all the windows and he will have to take off the siding and do some patching from the back of the house. I will ask him if he will put a piece in over this. Thank you for the replies.